# ttk equivalent of tix.FileEntry

Tags: tkinter, ttk, tix

I am looking for a ttk equivalent of `tix.FileEntry`. As I read, tix is not actively maintained, and it is preferred to use ttk instead. (and tix `FileEntry` is ugly)

So what is the ttk cousin of `tix.FileEntry`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent, but it's trivially easy to create one. A tix.FileEntry widget is nothing more than a label, entry widget, and a button to open a file dialog.